# How can one wish someone a "bonne nuit" when they sleep during the day?

Tags: expressions

Bob worked all night: he'll sleep from 9 am to 6 pm. What expression can one employ to wish him a "bonne nuit" right before he goes to sleep? "Bonne nuit" sounds a bit strange when said in the morning, and I wonder whether there exists a more appropriate expression.

Comment: Something like "dors bien", maybe?

Comment: Side note, *Bonne nuit* can still be used in a funny way, especially with someone you know well.

Answer (score 4):

You can wish someone a good [night's] sleep with « Beaux rêves » or « Fais de beaux rêves » for "sweet dreams" or « Dors bien » as mentioned in a comment by @spaghettibaguetti.

Comment: Yes, the complete expression is "Fais de beaux rêves".